# pandoc-crossref doesn't show figure/equations numbers in MS Word

Tags: pandoc

I asked this question, [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/vHfatcFjJKQ), but I didn't get any response so I decided to ask it here.

I started recently using pandoc to create Latex and docx documents. I have an issue regarding the cross-referencing in MS Word:
Here is the `myDoc.md` file

```
# Introduction

For $a \neq 0$ consider the follwoing equation:

$$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 $$ {#eq:quadformula}

The solutions of the equation \ref{quadformula} are given by:

$$ \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} $$
```

using the following command to convert it to docx:

```
pandoc .\myDoc.md -t docx  --filter pandoc-crossref -o myDoc.docx
```

In the MS document I can see the equation number but it doesn't write it in the sentence (missing equation number):

> ```
> The solutions of the equation (missing eqn number) are given by:
> ```

Or as shown by the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `pandoc-crossref` you're creating the label right, but you're calling it wrong. Try this:

```
# Introduction

For $a \neq 0$ consider the following equation:

$$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 $$ {#eq:quadformula}

The solutions of the equation [@eq:quadformula] are given by:

$$ \dfrac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} $$
```

Comment: Thank you , I forgot to mention that it was solved in google groups. Thank you for making this answer.